# While installing LaTeX I'm getting an error: permission denied for cefpdflatex.exe

Tags: installing

```
An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
  source line: 686
  message: Permission denied: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64/cefpdflatex.exe
  info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64/cefpdflatex.exe
```